# prevent sql injection

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Is there  a way to prevent sql injection by using stored procedures?

I have a sql query as

```
select column name from table where field ='@value'
cmd.parameters.add('@value', value);
```

I am using parameterized queries with least privileges. How can i write a basic stored procedure to prevent an sql injection.  Is that possible?

Comment: you should read up on prepared statements, they do exactly that, without a stored procedure.

Comment: It looks like this `.add()` function is in C# based on some of the answers below. If not, please remove the tag I'm about to add :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 select column name from table where field =@value
```

```
 cmd.parameters.add('@value', value);
```

SQL Parameters avoid the sql injection problem.

You just need to change the = condition with parameter. check above query.

Answer (score 6):

Using parameterized queries alone should already prevent sql injection attacks as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using parameterised queries, you should not need the quotes around @value (`@value` instead of `'@value'`), provided the @value parameter is defined as a string.

Creating a stored procedure works in the same kind of way.  @value would be defined as a VARCHAR or something, and so only accept strings.  Then you reference `@value` rather than `'@value'` in the stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc (IN @value VARCHAR(32))
BEGIN
  SELECT column name FROM table WHERE field = @value
END
```

Answer (score 0):

C#

```
   cmd.parameters.Add("?value", value);
```

is deprecated

to update for @Yogesh Bhadauirya stated,

```
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?value", value);
```