# asp.net c# Multiple search from tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I want to make a search function but I need to search from 1 textbox against multiple columns.
For example I have:

```
string select="Select * From tableName where(Name like'%" + texbox1.text.ToString() + "'";
sqldatasource1.selectcommand = select;
```

via that code I can only search in table Name.  How can I extend this to work against many columns?

Sql database 2008
Thanks

Comment: 1. Read up about SQL injection because you're open to that.  2. How would the code know that you wanted to search another column/would you always search several columns?

Comment: you have security issues here. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612306/prevent-sql-injection

Comment: Use FullText search on the database, will make it a whole lot easier

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. Are you asking how to search over multiple columns? If so, your where-clause is simply:

```
where Column1 like '%'" + textbox1.text.ToString() + " OR Column2 like '%'" + textbox1.text.ToString(); // ... and so on
```

But please don't build your query string as shown since this exposes you to an SQL injection attack! Use named parameters instead.

Answer (score -1):

string query = "select * from ProductDetails where ProductNamelike '" +SearchTextBox.Text+"%'"+"or ProductType like'"+SearchTextBox.Text+"%'";

Comment: Please do not give code-only answers. Additionally your answer is dangerous, its not secure against SQL injections.